# Retrieve json field value with importJSON

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a problem with google spreadsheets. I try to import a value from a link (which returns me a JSON) but it seems like it does not work.
I tried this:
https://medium.com/@paulgambill/how-to-import-json-data-into-google-spreadsheets-in-less-than-5-minutes-a3fede1a014a#.pb26xo98x
The link returns a json like this:

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "time": "2016-10-16T07:00:00+0000",
         "value": "249.884067074"
      }
   ],
   "summary": {
      "name": "Custom Events",
      "period": "daily",
      "since": "2016-10-17T00:00:00+0000",
      "until": "2016-10-17T00:00:00+0000"
   }
}
```

How can I extract the `value` from the `data` field?
I tried like this:

```
=ImportJSON(myUrl, "/data[0]/value", "noInherit,noTruncate,rawHeaders")
```

Comment: As this is a custom piece of code I'd suggest you ask in the comments of the article.

Answer (score 1):

According to [a comment](http://blog.fastfedora.com/projects/import-json#comment-20343) on the project page there is a fix that should be manually applied:

> Chris says:
>   November 4, 2014 at 11:35 pm  (UTC -4)
>
> Trevor,
>
> I was able to fix this problem by making a minor change to the
>   ParseData_ function. I changed line 286 in version 1.2.1 to:
>
> if (i >= 0 && data[state.rowIndex]) {
>
> and it seems to have addressed the issue.
>
> Thank you!
>
> CR